# Bind dropdown and textbox list dynamically in angular 2

Tags: angular, nlp-question-answering

I have one requirement for change password. There is a question dropdown and a textbox for answers. This will be generated dynamically in loop. I am able to generate it with below code:

```html
<ng-template let-i="index" let-c="count" ngFor let-question [ngForOf]="QuestionModel">

<div class="col-md-8" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
<select class="form-control custom-select col-12" required >
        <option *ngFor="let myQuest of QuestionModel;"  [value]="myQuest.QuestionID"> {{myQuest.SecurityQuestion}} </option>
</select>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="QuestionModel[i]['SecurityAns']" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"   />
</div>
</ng-template>
```

I am using two way binding. The problem is that i cannot identify which answer belongs to which question. Below is the model where i have to update the selected answer.

```js
{QuestionID: "0", SecurityQuestion: "What city were you born in?", SecurityAns: null}
{QuestionID: "1", SecurityQuestion: "What is the name of your best friend?", SecurityAns: null}
{QuestionID: "2", SecurityQuestion: "What is the name of your pet?", SecurityAns: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an ngModel on the select element:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
```

Comment: this is not working. By this, it is updating all the dropdowns selected value on change of any of dropdown. i am not able to pass selected dropdowns referance to textbox dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the select element:
`<select (change)="onQuestionChange($event)" >`
Create the `onQuestionChange()` method in your ts file. The event argument will hold the property that you have binded to the `value` property of the `<option>` element.

Then you can get the question associated to this I'd from your `QuestionModel`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have found a work around for my problem. My updated code is as below:

```html
 <ng-template let-i="index" let-c="count" ngFor let-question [ngForOf]="QuestionModel_ddl">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="SecurityQuestion">Security Question {{i+1}} :</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-control custom-select col-12" (change)="UpdateModelDtls($event, i)" required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let myQuest of QuestionModel_ddl;" [value]="myQuest.QuestionID"> {{myQuest.SecurityQuestion}} </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="SecurityQuestion">Security Answer :</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="QuestionModel_ddl[i]['SecurityAns']" required (focusout)="UpdateSeqAnswer($event, i)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
```

I have added two method UpdateModelDtls and UpdateSeqAnswer. And in Component, have defined it as

```html
UpdateModelDtls($event: any, i: any) {
        debugger;

        var item = this.selectedDtls.find(x => x.Index == i);
        /* Check if item already present in selectedDtls array. If present, show msg as 'This question is already selected, please select a different question.'  */
        var IsPresent = this.selectedDtls.find(x => x.QID == this.QuestionModel_ddl[($event.target.selectedIndex - 1)]['QuestionID'] && x.Index != i);

        /* In case all the questions dropdowns are selected */
        if (item) {
            /* Remove the changed dropdown from selectedDtls array since we are making it as not-selected */

            var index = this.selectedDtls.indexOf(item);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.selectedDtls.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        
        if (IsPresent) {
            this.IsDuplicateQuestion = true;
            $event.target.selectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else {

            this.IsDuplicateQuestion = false;
            let item = {
                QID: this.QuestionModel_ddl[($event.target.selectedIndex - 1)]['QuestionID'],
                Index: i,
                SeqAns: this.QuestionModel_ddl[i]['SecurityAns']
            };
            this.selectedDtls.push(item);
        }
    }

    UpdateSeqAnswer($event: any, i: any) {
        debugger;
        var item = this.selectedDtls.find(x => x.Index == i);
        if (item)
            item.SeqAns = $event.target.value;
    }
```

```html
export class SelectedDtls {
    QID: string;
    Index: number;
    SeqAns: string;
}
```

These two methods help to keep a temporary array (SelectedDtls) updated with the selected values.